# SQL Server - data lost when converted datetime to varchar

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

I had to restore a table that contained a datetime column.
I used bulk insert to insert the data from a CSV file. However the import couldn't insert the datetime values because SQL server saw it as a different format.

I ended up modifying the table, removing the datetime data type and replacing it with a varchar.

The issue is the data got converted from this format: `7/15/2015 3:41:57 PM` to something like this: `47:47.0`

Is there a way I can convert these values back or is the data lost?

Comment: That isn't the SQL Server canonical format for DATETIME data type. The true format should be YYYY-MM-DD H:m:s:ms.

Comment: Ok, is there anyway I can convert the 47:47.0 to that format?

Comment: In the CSV file what format is the date?

Comment: You'll need to get the data from the CSV file again... that value is hosed.

Comment: As @ChrisSteele mentioned, your data is hosed. It likely got this way by Excel's cool feature to convert datetime strings to integers. Try re-saving the original file in notepad, or changing the format of the column from Date/Datetime to Text if you're using Excel.

Comment: @BrentD, that was the issue. Stupid Excel. Got it working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ChrisSteele mentioned, your data is hosed. It likely got this way by Excel's cool feature to convert datetime strings to integers. Try re-saving the original file in notepad, or changing the format of the column from Date/Datetime to Text if you're using Excel.